# VSCode C# extension is "missing content-length"

Tags: c#

when I make a new c# text file in vscode it comes up with this:

```
Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)' Failed to download from https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/coreclr-debug-1-25-1/coreclr-debug-win7-x64.zip. No content-length header
Failed at stage: downloadPackage
Missing content-length
```

I'm not sure why it does this and I've tried a lot of things but I'm still a beginner so I cant really do much about it.

I tried to download the package and tried to put vsc in it but to no avail.

Comment: Download the .NET Core Debugger `extension`. Name: .NET Install Tool for Extension VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime

Comment: I downloaded it but nothing happened... it still says the same thing.

Comment: maybe you should restart your vscode

Comment: I did that many times already